# How to sort Json_encode on php?

Tags: php, sql, json

I have a .php file that gets data from SQL and then produces them as json array using json_encode. What I would like to know is, is it possible to sort them? or anything along those lines? Thanks

Comment: Your question is leaving a lot to the imagination. What sort of array are you dealing with: one- or multi-dimensional? numeric- or string-indexed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort, order, group or whatever you like them in either the sql query or through array manipulation before using json_encode.

json_encode (as it is clear from its name) is only used for **encoding** the data, not sorting etc. Whatever you give it, it will just encode/serialize to json.